# How do I stop my (google cloud) server with a bitnami couchdb instance from filling up with logs?

Tags: logging, debian, couchdb, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I installed a [bitnami couchdb stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/couchdb) and when a few users logged in straight away it filled up the couchdb log folder (/opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log/couchdb) to the full size of the server.

I changed the local.ini file to log less (sudo vi /opt/bitnami/couchdb/etc/couchdb/local.ini) by setting logging to warning rather than debug (http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/config/logging.html) but it keeps filling up (I did restart couchdb with the command: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart couchdb).

I resized the server by taking a snapshot and creating a new bigger instance from it. I increazed it for 10 to 100gb. In the same time it took the previous log folder to create 4 gb of logs the new bigger server created 41 gb of logs even if it was set to warning.

The weirdest thing is that even after I deleted all the logs and the folder went from 41gb to 5mb the used space still says 67gb of 100 is being used (sudo lsblk).

Is my server writing other logs I need to change some setting on? 
My cpu is also going very high; could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami engineer here,

Bitnami stacks include Logrotate that is designed to ease administration of systems that generate large numbers of log files. It allows automatic rotation, compression, removal, and mailing of log files.

Logrotate files for different servers are stored in the /opt/bitnami/config/logrotate/logrotate.d directory. Recent versions of Bitnami stacks ship logrotate configuration files for all servers. If you are using a virtual machine or cloud image, logrotate is already configured and enabled by default. You can check if it's working properly by running this command

```
sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/bitnami.conf
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/components/logrotate/

We also suggest you check the content of those log files. In case you performed a change in the configuration, the server might not be working correctly and that is why the log is so big. Once you've checked it, please post the content of it here in order to debug the error.

Regards,
Jota

Comment: Handling 1 logs
rotating pattern: /opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.*  weekly (150 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.stderr
  log does not need rotating
considering log /opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.stderr-20170705.gz
  log does not need rotating
considering log /opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.stdout
  log does not need rotating
considering log /opt/bitnami/couchdb/var/log/couchdb/couchdb.stdout-20170705.gz
  log does not need rotating

Comment: This is what I get back when I run the command:
sudo logrotate -d /etc/logrotate.d/bitnami.conf